# ClassNotFoundException Ant + JUnit

Tags: java, web, ant, junit

I have problems generating reports using JUnit + Ant. Same error happens here. My Ant file ( the part responsible for generating the reports + running the JUnit) looks like this:

```
    <formatter type="xml" />
    <formatter type="plain" />
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${sysLibs}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <pathelement location="${src}/tests" />
        <pathelement location="${sysLibs}/junit-4.11.jar" />

    </classpath>
    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${report-dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src}/tests">
            <include name="*Test.java" />
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
<junitreport todir="${report-dir}">
    <fileset dir="${report-dir}" includes="*.xml" />
    <report todir="${report-dir}" />
</junitreport>
```

Any idea why I got `ClassNotFoundException`?

Plus in the report, for each TestClass:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CaronaTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
**LOG**:
C:\Users\USER\workspace\projeto-si1>ant testa
Buildfile: C:\Users\USER\workspace\projeto-si1\build.xml

init:
     [echo] Criando diretorio de build e dist.

compila:
     [echo] Compilando o projeto.
    [javac] C:\Users\USER\workspace\projeto-si1\build.xml:55: warning: 'inclu
deantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false f
or repeatable builds
     [echo] Processo de compilacao concluido com sucesso.

testa:
    [junit] Running CaronaTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Test CaronaTest FAILED
    [junit] Running ControllerTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Test ControllerTest FAILED
    [junit] Running EasyAcceptTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Test EasyAcceptTest FAILED
    [junit] Running SessionControllerTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Test SessionControllerTest FAILED
    [junit] Running SolicitaCaronaTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Test SolicitaCaronaTest FAILED
    [junit] Running UserTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c


       [junit] Test UserTest FAILED
    [junitreport] the file C:\Users\USER\workspace\projeto-si1\xml-report\TESTS-T
    estSuites.xml is not a valid testsuite XML document
    [junitreport] Processing C:\Users\USER\workspace\projeto-si1\xml-report\TESTS
    -TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\null2126114800
    [junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/ant-junit.jar
    !/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl

[junitreport] Transform time: 294ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\null2126114800

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: Can it be, that the classpath sould be `${src}`? it must be the binary o think. Maybe ist called buld.